# Venom web how to do it in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

how to do it in unity venom web like this?

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7051349153674649600/

I did a lot of research but couldn't find it. maybe the joints will work but I couldn't figure out how to do it. they do not give exactly this result.

Answer (score 1):

Raycast to find a spot on a surface to connect to, then create a joint between object & surface with configurations that feels good for you.

This isn't really a question suitable for this forum though, since you're basically just asking strangers to do work for you.

I suggest you try something (you already have an idea it seems) and if it doesn't work, come back and ask around the problems you have, with code examples & unity setups